# Loop through array, set property of each element?

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, very simple: there is an array containing 3 objects.  Each object has a unique property called "ID" with values of either 1, 2, or 3.

One of the objects gets deleted.

The objective now is to update the ID property of each object corresponding to the new array.length value.

So for example, the object with ID of 2 got deleted.  The remaining objects in the array would each have ID values of 1 and 3 respectively.

So the objective is to loop through the array and update the ID properties to 1, and 2 (instead of 1 and 3).

So I guess the question is how to write a loop to update a common property of each element in an array.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for-loop to go through the array, as in walkietokyo's answer, or you can use a method closure:

```
myArray.forEach ( function ( item:*, i:int, arr:Array) : void { item.ID = i; } );
```

or a while-loop:

```
var i:int = -1;
while (++i < myArray.length) myArray[i].ID = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i:uint = 1; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].ID = i;
}
```

General info on loops:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var i:uint; // for speed keep out of the loop
var arrayLength = myArray.length // for speed keep out of the loop

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    myArray[i].ID = i;
}
```